# That these United Colonies are, and of Right ought to be

Tags: phrase-meaning

> We, therefore, the Representatives of the united States of America, in
> General Congress, Assembled, appealing to the Supreme Judge of the
> world for the rectitude of our intentions, do, in the Name, and by
> Authority of the good People of these Colonies, solemnly publish and
> declare, **That these United Colonies are, and of Right ought to be** Free
> and Independent States; that they are Absolved from all Allegiance to
> the British Crown, and that all political connection between them and
> the State of Great Britain, is and ought to be totally dissolved; […]

Source: [The Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript)

I understand "and of Right" as "and of course". Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "right" here means a statute of law or morality, as in '*human rights*'.

In this context, it means that the colonies *had the right* to be free.

A more modern way to say it would be "and *by* right ought to be", but this is from an old document.